# Call to static::<function> but function doesn't exist but it works (Laravel 5 Eloquent in particular, but it doesn't really matter)

Tags: php

I have been wondering for a while why this works. I have been working with Laravel 5.1 for a while and now I want to create my own framework (for learning purpose only). At the moment I am into Models and Database connections, and then there is this file. Which is extended by Models, such as Status and User models.

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php

This is the abstract Model class which isn't too bad. When setting up a Laravel 5.1 project there will be a User class that extends this, it is the possible to execute

> `User::where('username', 'Rasmus');`
>
> User is the user model that extends the abstract Model class
>
> 'username' refers to the the database column
>
> 'Rasmus' is what it is looking for in that column, it is my name...

The interesting part and the main thing in this question is that there is no "where" method in the Model class, nor the User class. The Model class does NOT inherit anything. Can someone explain to me why this works, (calling User::where) when the method does not exist.

Good to know is that `static::where(...);` is called a few times in the abstract Model class as well.

Sincerely, Rasmus Rosengren

A fellow PHP learner

Comment: Looks like that framework uses object morphing and traits. The method is defined in the `Eloquent\Builder` class. That is elegant, but extremely slow, since it relies on reflection.

Comment: @arkascha It doesn't rely on reflection. See `__call()` in `Model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model`'s `__call()` function passes it off to a `QueryBuilder` instance (with a few steps in between, but that's the fundamental end result).

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    ...

    $query = $this->newQuery();
    return call_user_func_array([$query, $method], $parameters);
}
```

`__call()` is [a magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) that lets the application deal with a missing/inaccessible method name. In this case, it allows the various `where()` methods (including being able to do stuff like *definitely* undefined functions like `whereUsername('Rasmus')`) to work.

Comment: Thanks, did not see it, if the method called (vie the magic method __call) is anything else that increment or decrement it switchs to the query builder. Thanks! Would have taken me years to figure it out... I was looking in the __callStatic magic method :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not programming expert and i do expect better answer on this. However, you might be interested in [QueryBuilder](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php) at line 447. While on Model.php you could see it uses QueryBuilder on line 27.

As i remember Laravel uses trait for handling several code reuse. It is rather advanced topic - which pretty interesting.